# Send variable to redis from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redis

this question - is it possible to send the value to the redis from jquery, let's say I pressed the button and the value from the text field was added to the redis, so that when changing to another page, the value should again be emitted from the redis

Comment: You cannot interact directly with redis (server side) from jquery (client side). You would need to write a server side api (eg using nodejs) that in-turn set/get from redis.

Comment: I need to use ajax ?

Comment: If it is a single page application, yes. Otherwise you already have server side processing and just need to interface with redis api there.